# Access Control List (ACL) for specific object

Tags: php, object, laravel, acl, rbac

I would like to use a ACL system with LARAVEL framework.

I understand that I can control the rights to resources such as the entity "Comment".
My "Moderator" role could "delete", "edit" any comment.

**However, how can I manage the rights for a specific "comment" ? which a user is the owner? I seek to combine the best practices ...**

Comment: You have any questions ?

Answer (score 1):

check this out 
https://github.com/efficiently/authority-controller

restricts what resources a given user is allowed to access.